# Below is the code snippet and error message, why compiler is asking for this default constructor?

Tags: java

```
class X{
    X(){
        System.out.println("Inside X()");
    }
    X(int x){
        System.out.println("Inside X(int)");
    }
}
class Y extends X{
    Y(String s){
        System.out.println("Inside Y(String)");
    }
    Y(int y){
        super(1000);
        System.out.println("Inside Y(int)");
    }
}
class Z extends Y{
    Z(){
        System.out.println("Inside Z()");
    }
    Z(int z){
        super(100);
        System.out.println("Inside Z(int)");
    }
}
public class Program{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Z z=new Z(10);
    }
}
```

The above code gives below error when compiled :-

Program.java:23: error: no suitable constructor found for Y(no arguments)

```
Z(){
   ^
constructor Y.Y(String) is not applicable

  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)

constructor Y.Y(int) is not applicable

  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

1 error

What is the use of default constructor when we are calling parameterized constructor, java compiler is giving error i am unable to understand why  this default constructor is required?

Comment: The first line of every constructor is either a `super()` or `this()` invocation; if you do not provide one the compiler will insert a `super()` for you by default. This is the source of the error, your parent class `Y` has no empty constructor. Explicitly call a constructor you do have instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You need to specify the constructor to be used to create the super class if it has no constructor without arguments (default one)** *

First statement in your constructors is a call to `super()` unless you indicate an explicit call to this or super with any arguments. That `super()` call is injected by java on compilación time. Therefore it is looking for non-args constructor at Y class.

Please refer to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html):

> Note: If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass
>   constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the
>   no-argument constructor of the superclass. If the super class does not
>   have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error.
>   Object does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only
>   superclass, there is no problem.

In practice, compiler will pre-process your code and produce something like:

```
class X{
    X(){
        super(); // Injected by compiler
        System.out.println("Inside X()");
    }
    X(int x){
        super(); // Injected by compiler
        System.out.println("Inside X(int)");
    }
}
class Y extends X{
    Y(String s){
        super(); // Injected by compiler
        System.out.println("Inside Y(String)");
    }
    Y(int y){
        super(1000);
        System.out.println("Inside Y(int)");
    }
}
class Z extends Y{
    Z(){ 
        super(); // Injected by compiler
        System.out.println("Inside Z()");
    }
    Z(int z){
        super(100);
        System.out.println("Inside Z(int)");
    }
}
public class Program{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Z z=new Z(10);
    }
}
```

Then It will proceed to compile it, however as you see, Z non-argument constructor try to reference Y non-argument constructor, which does not exist.

*As Carlos Heuberger clarify.

Comment: or, in other words, you must specify the constructor to be used to create the super class (part of the new instance) if it has no constructor without arguments (default one)

Comment: "If a constructor does not explicetly invoke a superclass constructor, java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the super class"
but i have explicitly invoked argument constructor,
I am calling the super(100) from class Z and it should call the arguments constructor of Y class instead of asking for default constructor so why compiler is asking for default constructor?

Comment: That is correct, however it is your Z() constructor the one looking for a way to initialize Y class. Even when you do not use that constructor, at compile time java inject the super()